# How can I rotate log files monthly using Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, logging, rotation

In Unix, I need to be able to archive log files into monthly folders, labelled accordingly. How do I do this in Perl?

Comment: You might want to try Googling this one, or provide more information about your specific needs. This has been done, and documented in many places. 

http://oreilly.com/catalog/perlsysadm/chapter/ch09.html

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's provide an actual Perl idea, since that's what was asked for:

```
use File::Path qw<mkpath>;
use File::Spec;
use POSIX qw<strftime>;
use Smart::Comments;

my $directory 
    = File::Spec->catfile( $BASE_LOG_DIRECTORY
                         , strftime( "%Y-%B", localtime ) #2009-January
    );
### $directory
unless ( -e $directory ) {
    mkpath( $directory, { verbose => 1 } );
}
my $log_file_path = File::Spec->catfile( $directory, 'system.log' );
### $log_file_path
```

Output is

```
### $directory: '/my/base/directory/2009-January'
### $log_file_path: '/my/base/directory/2009-January/system.log'
```

Notes

1. Install `Smart::Comments`, or comment it out.
2. The constant `$BASE_LOG_DIRECTORY` is written in Readonly/PBP style
3. Everything else should just come with Perl.

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to be Perl? Have you tried logrotate?

As far as a Perl solution: **mkdir** will create the directories, and if you **use POSIX 'strftime';**, then you'll be able to generate nice directory names based on the current time (ie, **my $dirname = strftime('%Y-%m-%d',localtime())** will generate a YYYY-MM-DD string), and you can move the files using **rename**. That's just core Perl, there are a ton of CPAN modules that do some or all of this (such as File::Copy, instead of rename).

Answer (score 2):

When I have had this task, I use [cronolog](http://cronolog.org/usage.html).

The package includes a Perl script called `cronosplit` that you can use to split an existing monolithic log file into `%Y/%m/%d` subdirectories.

Cronolog itself is a binary written in C that can be used as a piped target for logging.  For example, you can use it in an Apache httpd.conf:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /web/logs/%Y/%m/%d/access.log"
```